# How to run laravel Homestead with Mongo db?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use MongoDB with laravel homestead, it's already installed on my host maching "Windows 7", how can I install it on the virtual Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you check out the scripts directory for the Vaprobash project, since it would be a good starting point to see how others install services like MondoDB on an Ubuntu host:

[Vaprobash Github Scripts Directory](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/tree/master/scripts)

There is one there labeled "mongodb.sh" that shows probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the link. `mongo.sh` is really great.

Answer (score 2):

I used this script [Mongostead7](https://github.com/zakhttp/Mongostead7)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @noeldiaz's answer, this is what I use to semi-automate adding Mongo to Homestead (correct for Windows Git Bash, may have to be adapted for other shells):

```
# Set the correct Homestead dir
HOMESTEAD_DIR=/c/Users/${USERNAME}/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/laravel/homestead
# Download vaprobash and enable mongodb on the fly
curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaamaru/Homestead-Vaprobash-Scripts/master/vaprobash.rb | sed 's/# \(config\.vm\.provision .*mongodb.*\)/\1/g' > ${HOMESTEAD_DIR}/scripts/vaprobash.rb
# Add a call to vaprobash into the Vagrantfile
echo -e "\nrequire File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/vaprobash.rb')\n" >> ${HOMESTEAD_DIR}/Vagrantfile
# Pick up the new settings
homestead provision
```

Hope that helps someone.